# What are "collaborator associations" on GitHub?

Tags: github

When you delete a repository on GitHub, it comes with this warning:

> This action **CANNOT** be undone. This will permanently delete the **<repository name>** repository, wiki, issues, and comments, and remove all collaborator associations.

I know a "collaborator" is a user who has permissions to push etc. to a repository. I guess in this context "remove all collaborator associations" means the list of collaborators for the repository will be lost when the repository is deleted. However, it's not clear what this means in the case where the repository being deleted is a fork of another repository.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] remove all collaborator associations.

This means that upon deletion of a repository, the 'contributors' list will also be deleted.

This list is visible on the right side of the page for existing repositories:

[Example contributors list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW03K.png)

(Example taken from [turnipguy30/turnipguy30](https://github.com/turnipguy30/turnipguy30))

> [...] it's not clear what this means in the case where the repository being deleted is a fork [...]

In the case of a fork, the 'contributors' list could be different from that of the source repository if the fork has had changes made to it.

I hope this helps.